# How can I capture complete path along with intermediate nodes in mininet?

Tags: python-3.x, mininet

I am working on mininet simulator and I want to know a way to capture complete path from source to destination.
I have tried this with wireshark but only I can get is source and destination address in icmp packet.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use *traceroute* or even *pathping*.

Comment: I have tried traceroute but it only shows destination ip. I need to know complete path. well, when I ping n monitor Wireshark it only shows controller, switch connected to controller, source and destination packets.

one thing I want to add is that I am working on inband SDN.